# how to associate a folders name with a icon

Tags: icons, directory, icon-themes, personalization

Is there any way within Linux that when i create a folder it automatically gains a system icon based on its name? For example if i create a folder named "java" it will be created automatically with the folder-java icon.

Visual identification could improve the use of the computer since my current monitor does not facilitate the reading of texts

I've searched all over the internet but haven't found anything that works. Most of the answers ask to change manually but I find it a little inconvenient given the amount of folders that I will have to change manually

Comment: You can simply refresh the screen of `Files`, or whatever program you're running. "Icons" aren't separate files, rather they're artifacts of the file browser.